# Need to add values in a column corresponding to the week (Python/Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing dates and prices. I need to add all prices belonging to the week of ex: 17/12 to 23/12 and put it infront of a new label corresponding to that week.

```
  Date            Price
12/17/2015         10
12/18/2015         20
12/19/2015         30
12/21/2015         40
12/24/2015         50
```

I want the output to be the following

```
   week            total
17/12-23/12         100
24/12-30/12         50
```

I tried using different datetime functions and groupby functions but was not able to get the o/p. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this approach?

```
In [19]: df.groupby(df.Date.dt.weekofyear)['Price'].sum().rename_axis('week_no').reset_index(name='total')
Out[19]:
   week_no  total
0       51     60
1       52     90
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [49]: df.resample(on='Date', rule='7D', base='4D').sum().rename_axis('week_from') \
           .reset_index('total')
Out[49]:
   week_from  Price
0 2015-12-17    100
1 2015-12-24     50
```

**UPDATE2:**

```
x = (df.resample(on='Date', rule='7D', base='4D')
       .sum()
       .reset_index()
       .rename(columns={'Price':'total'}))

x = x.assign(week=x['Date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m')
                  +'-'
                  +(x.pop('Date')+pd.DateOffset(days=7)).dt.strftime('%d/%m'))


In [127]: x
Out[127]:
   total         week
0    100  17/12-24/12
1     50  24/12-31/12
```

Comment: the week is from midweek to midweek. Your solution is nice but it arranges things according to the calendar. If I want to start from 17 and keep counting weeks after that, how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Using resample

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index(df.Date, inplace = True)
df = df.resample('W').sum()

            Price
Date    
2015-12-20  60
2015-12-27  90
```